# WIN64DUALFOLDERS issue

Tags: windows-installer

Of late I have started to observe a weird issue while installing a 32-bit application (created using installshield) on a 64-bit Windows 7 OS.

The following is found in the log:

> MSI (s) (68:64) [00:30:39:917]: Executing op:
>   ActionStart(Name=ProcessComponents,Description=Updating component
>   registration,) MSI (s) (68:64) [00:30:39:917]: Executing op:
>   ProgressTotal(Total=1,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=24000) MSI (s) (68:64)
>   [00:30:39:917]: Executing op:
>   ComponentRegister(ComponentId={0770248C-8066-4600-A88D-B83BE48A1B57},KeyPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\RI\Port\PortFTPA.exe,State=3,,Disk=1,SharedDllRefCount=2,BinaryType=0)
>   MSI (s) (68:64) [00:30:39:917]: **WIN64DUALFOLDERS: Substitution in
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\RI\Port\PortFTPA.exe'
>   folder had been blocked by the 1 mask argument (the folder pair's
>   iSwapAttrib member = 0)**.

An older version of the EXE '**PortFTPA.exe**' is already present on the OS at **C:\Program Files (x86)\RI\Port**. I created another custom MSI using installshield to overwrite the EXE with a newer version of the same.

In the '**Summary Information Stream**', I configured it to be a 32-bit installer and also configured the component containing the EXE to install to the [ProgramFilesFolder] location.

Yet, the file fails to be replaced.

Please help.

Comment: I don't know how all your components are configured, 64-bit or 32-bit, but that's what makes the difference, keeping in mind a 64-bit MSI can have 32 and 64-bit components but not vice versa. The rule that is being applied is that 32-bit components will always go in the 32-bit program files folder and 64-bit components always in the 64-bit program files folder, redirected if necessary. That should explain what you're seeing, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.
1. If your already installed file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\RI\Port\..` is a Windows Installer package then you have to uninstall it and install the new one or you can do a update, but keep in mind that you have to increase the Version number of `PortFTPA.exe`.
2. The installed program under `C:\Program Files (x86)\RI\Port\..` is legacy manufactor setup. In this case you have to repackage the whole application und try to uninstall the existing installations by the manufactors uninstall routine.
So this isn't a easy question, we need more informations.